# Estimate the variation of solution in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the initial value problem, $$y' = x + e^x\sin(xy), \; y(0) = 0 =y_0$$
estimate the variation of the solution in the interval [0,1] if $y_0$ is perturbed by 0.01.

The way I use to approach this problem is let $y_0 = 0.001, y_1 = 0$, then we can use Lipschitz condition to show that
$$|y(x,x_1,y_1) - y(x,x_0,y_0)| \leqslant |y_0 - y_1|e^{L|x-x_0|} \\
                                \leqslant 0.001e^1 
$$
But, I am not sure about this approach though

Comment: You should have $x_1=x_0$, else the Grönwall formula is not correct. How did you get $L=1$ as Lipschitz constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see how yo use the Lipschitz condition. Let $y$ be the solution with $y(0)=y_0$ and $z$ the solution with $z(0)=z_0$. Then
$$\begin{align}
|y(x)-z(x)|&\le|y_0-z_0|+\int_0^xe^t\,|\sin(t\,y(t))-\sin(t\,z(t))|\,dt\\
&\le|y_0-z_0|+\int_0^xt\,e^t\,|y(t)-z(t)|\,dt.
\end{align}$$
By Gronwall's lemma
$$
|y(x)-z(x)|\le|y_0-z_0|\exp\left(\int_0^xt\,e^t\,dt\right)=|y_0-z_0|\exp(x\,e^x-e^x+1).
$$
In your case $y_0=0$, $z_0=0.01$ and
$$
\sup_{0\le x\le1}|y(x)-z(x)|\le0.01\,e.
$$

Comment: I ended up like that because after all the proof in book, and that is what I concluded in my answer. I should have mentioned that the proof is in "Introduction to Ordinary Differential Equation by Ravi. P Agarwal"